# Is this function borel-measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\ \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{\sin(x)} & x\notin \{z|z=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\ \\  
0 & x\in \{z|z=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}\} \
\end{cases}$ borel-measurable? If so, which way can I show that? By now I only know that characterstic functions are measurable and linear combinations, products of measurable functions are... nothing about continuous functions. I also tried splitting it up by using characteristic functions which didn't work.

Comment: Every continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable (Trivial by the definition of a measurable function)

Comment: but $f$ isn't continuous ?

Comment: approaching 0 from the left side gets me $-\infty$, but $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable. In this case, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$, where $A$ = {$x : x= k \pi , k \in \mathbb{Z}$}.

By definition, $f$ is measurable iff {$x| f(x)>a$} is measurable for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Claim:

{$x| f(x)>a$}= $(f^{-1}(a, \infty) \cap$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$) $\cup A$.

Proof:

By continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$, {$x| f(x)>a$} = {$x| 1/sin(x)>a$}= $f^{-1}(a, \infty) \cap$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$. When $f(x)= 0$ is taken into consideration, we have {$x| f(x)>a$} = $A$. In general,{$x| f(x)>a$} is the union of those two sets.

---

$f^{-1}(a, \infty) \cap$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$ is the intersection two Borel sets. Hence, it is Borel.$A$is Borel  as well; so does the union of two Borel measurable sets. Therefore, {$x| f(x)>a$} is Borel. By defintion, $f$ is Borel measurable.

Note that, $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ is  Borel because of the continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A$.

Comment: how do you get $\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Fixed it.Anyways, it doesn't affect my answer.